# Loosing reputation points for voting an answer down - why?

Tags: discussion

So this is not a linux question, but one about the forums. I am new to this site as you can see. I have been using linux a while and I find this site very helpful.

However I see on the rules if you downvote a answer, you also lose a reputation point. While I can understand you dont want everyone downvoting answers, isn’t it better if people who know what they are talking about downvote an answer that, for example, is proved to not work or to be malicious, rather than the original poster triying that option (and wasting time) even if it doesnt work? If you lose a reputation point no-one will be willing to downvote bad answers?

Can someone please explain the logic...

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-down-voting http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93023/why-do-i-not-lose-reputation-when-i-downvote-posts http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not and many more https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=loose++rep+for+downvoteing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0ZkHV4GxBcTAaNazs-AH

Comment: " If you lose a reputation point no-one will be willing to downvote bad answers" Of course they will, you don't loose your privileges when you loose rep and if the answer is removed (if it is so bad you should flag it too) you get the rep back.

Comment: @markkirby lose enough rep and you will lose privileges.

Comment: I agree with the loss of rep, it prevents robo downvoting - far better to leave a comment asking for clarification or additional information. I tend to down vote only things that are actually harmful or could result in data loss. Otherwise there is ofter at least 2 ways to accomplish a taask and who is to say A is better then B